# Getting directory listing from SVN for use in ANT dropdown

Tags: svn, ant, coldfusion, antform

I've done some Googling on this but I can't seem to find anything along the lines of what I'm needing.

I'm using ANTForms for the GUI on our deployment. Developers can choose the build from the **dynamically populated dropdown**, hit ok and away it goes.

The way the dropdown is dynamically populated at the moment is by ANT making an HTTP webservice call to our ColdFusion server giving it a list of needed SVN directories. CF then uses a bit of underlining Java to call SVNKit and return a query result for CF to process. It converts this to a comma-separated list, outputs it for ANT and it then builds these dropdowns options.

I'm using CF because that's our main language. I don't really know any Java but what's bugging me a bit here is if I did I know I could get ANT to talk to Java / SVNKit directly and therefore cut CF out the picture completely. It would probably also remove the need for the HTTP call as the SVN setup is local so a speed increase is there + it takes out the reliance on a external source.

Has anyone done this or do you know any working examples I could see that show ANT talking to SVNKit directly to do this kind of thing?

I had a look at the usual SVN ANT tasks over at Subclipse but they don't have any way of doing this.

Any help appreciated,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to build something in Java why not generate your ANTForm configuration file using XLST, based on the XML output produced by the standard subversion client:

```
svn list --xml http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/tags > releases.xml
```

Produces the following *releases.xml* file (I've edited it for clarity):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lists>
  <list path="http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/tags">
    <entry ..>
      <name>1.4.1</name>
      ..
    </entry>
    <entry ..>
      <name>2.0.0</name>
      ..
    </entry>
  </list>
</lists>
```

### Example

Example is comprised of two files

- genGUI.xml
- genGUI.xsl

Run as follows:

```
ant -f genGUI.xml
```

**genGUI.xml**

```
<project name="genGUI" default="run">

    <property name="repo.url"  value="http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/tags"/>
    <property name="build.dir" location="build"/>
    <property name="xsl.file"  location="genGUI.xsl"/>
    <property name="data.file" location="${build.dir}/data.xml"/>
    <property name="run.file"  location="${build.dir}/run.xml"/>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="get-data" depends="init">
        <exec executable="svn" failonerror="true" output="${data.file}">
            <arg line="list --xml ${repo.url}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="generate" depends="get-data">
        <xslt style="${xsl.file}" in="${data.file}" out="${run.file}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="generate">
        <ant antfile="${run.file}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

**genGUI.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="antform-home">${env.ANTFORM_HOME}</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <project name="genForm" default="menu">

            <property environment="env"/>

            <path id="runtime.cp">
                <pathelement location="{$antform-home}/lib/antform.jar"/>
            </path>

            <target name="menu">
                <taskdef name="antmenu" classname="com.sardak.antform.AntMenu" classpathref="runtime.cp"/>

                <antmenu image="{$antform-home}/doc/images/logo-small.jpg" title="My simple form" stylesheet="{$antform-home}/style.test">
                    <label>Form is generated from subversion</label>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="lists/list/entry"/>
                </antmenu>
            </target>

        </project>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <button label="{name}" target="{name}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```