# Parsing inmemory XML parameter in ANT

Tags: xml, ant, properties

In my ant script i have a property which contains XML format string.

For example i get this property using this call:

```
<exec executable="svn" outputproperty="svnout">
    <arg value="proplist"/>
    <arg value="-v"/>
    <arg value="--xml"/>
</exec>
```

So my svnout property contains following value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
<target
   path=".">
<property
   name="svn:ignore">.git&#13;
*.iml&#13;
</property>
</target>
</properties>
```

I need to get content of  element and i don't want to save this property in file.

xmlproperty task is not applicable here, because it reads from file, but i need to read from memory. Is there any way to parse XML property without writing it on disk?

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT to parse the XML file returned by subversion in a manner similar to the following answer:

- [Getting directory listing from SVN for use in ANT dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530181/getting-directory-listing-from-svn-for-use-in-ant-dropdown/3534025#3534025)

But I think you should consider using an embedded script to parse the XML.